# Mirror an ftp site, but create empty files instead of full files to save bandwidth

Tags: ftp, wget, bandwidth

I want a listing of all files and directories at `ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/snp/`. But I don't want to download the contents of all the files.

To save bandwidth, I hoped that `wget` would have an option to simply create empty files locally instead of downloading every file. But it appears not to have such an option. Any suggestions?

I don't have any access to the machine, other than this read-only public ftp access.

Comment: Why don't you just pipe the list of files to a text and upload that.

Comment: I don't have shell access, so I can't get the list of files except through ftp. And I don't want to upload anything. I don't understand your suggestion, @Ramhound

Comment: (See my answer, it might clarify what my question is) I don't understand anything about your comment :-).  I've given the address of an `ftp` site. I don't have any rights to make changes to that ftp site. It has a deep directory structure, so I want to get a full listing of all the files in all the directories and subdirectories of that ftp site. I do not want the contents of the files, as that would be many gigabytes.

Comment: How would I know you don't have any permissions?

Answer (score 0):

(Answering own question)

This is very slow, but it kinda solves my problem.

```
wget -r --no-remove-listing --spider ftp://myftpserver/ftpdirectory/
```

From http://biocozy.blogspot.ch/2012/03/how-to-get-entire-recursive-directory.html

`--spider` means that it doesn't download the file, which is good. Also, `--no-remove-listing` means the directory listing is kept in each directory in a file called `.listing`. The bad news is that `--spider` causes `wget` to test for the presence of each file that is supposed to be in the directory, and this seems to slow it down a lot.

Anything faster?